# In Apache, if 403s aren't appearing in error.log, how can I get them to appear?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, logging, wordpress

Apache2 under Ubuntu 12.04

I get a 403 error only sometimes when a URL is passed to a PHP script in WordPress via the PressThis button.  e.g.

```
http://dev.wakawaka.com/wp-admin/press-this.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foohoo.org%2Fpb%2FThe-Future-of-Our-Schools&t=The%20Future%20of%20Our%20Schools%3A%20Teachers%20Unions%20and%20Social%20Justice%20%7C%20Haymarket%20Books&s=&v=4
```

This results in a 403 in the browser, and access.log is appended.  But error.log is not appended.

Other URLs don't fail - they work properly, such as

```
"GET /wp-admin/press-this.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yeehaw.com%2Fproducts%2Fduet2.php&t=Apogee%20Duet%202%20-%202%20IN%20x%204%20OUT%20USB%20audio%20interface&s=&v=4 HTTP/1.1" 200 7962 "http://www.apogeedigital.com/products/duet2.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17"
```

I have set `loglevel` to the most verbose setting of `emerg`.  No error appears when the 403 is thrown.

Also, I have edited `.htaccess` to a minimal version that does no security and the condition still persists for some URLs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

By setting your [LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel) to Emerg (Emergencies - system is unusable.) you have reduced logging to it's minimum amount and only the most serious conditions are logged. You will need to increase log verbosity to at least `Error` to see 403's being logged.

```
LogLevel Error
```

restart the apache service and you should be good.

Comment: thanks.  unfortunately, made the change, cleared browser cache, hit the offending URL as above and no change to error.log.  The last entry shows the server restarting.

Comment: @Miller: This works on the systems (Ubuntu and CentOS) I have to hand. Did you restart Apache after making the change ? Does the vhost you're connecting to have it's own ErrorLog directive ?

Comment: did restart, no change.  The server directive for the vhost in question is ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log  with an accompanying  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Comment: I did notice that access.log is showing a 403 plus 407 error that I had overlooked.  Here's an example of a URL that fails:

http://pastebin.com/04f724Fc

Comment: Note also please the error text presented in the browser reflects the 407 error, but I am logged in  - to WordPress, so I don't understand what's going on.

You are not authorized to access the webpage at http://dev.cityblocchicago.com/wp-admin/press-this.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.haymarketbooks.org%2Fpb%2FThe-Future-of-Our-Schools&t=The%20Future%20of%20Our%20Schools%3A%20Teachers%20Unions%20and%20Social%20Justice%20%7C%20Haymarket%20Books&s=&v=4. You may need to sign in.